# Mamp Pro renders without styles in Firefox but correctly in other browsers

Tags: apache, firefox, mamp-pro, drupal-9, php-8.1

for years I've used Mamp (free), but now I pretend to buy pro version, so I've recently installed demo of Mamp Pro and made a few sites work, however, there is one Drupal 9 site that works fine in most browsers, except in Firefox. It renders a non-styled page. It was fine when I used Mamp (free).

What I have tried is to inspect page source of Firefox and compared it to the page source of Chrome, the result of this was that the HTML code is the same in both, and that there are not bad closed HTML tags.

Any idea of what is happening?

- Mamp Pro 6.6.4.
- Drupal 9.4.9
- Firefox 108.0.1 (64-bit)
- PHP max_execution_time = 30
- PHP memory_limit = -1
- PHP max_input_time = -1

**Mamp settings**
[image: Mamp settings]

**Apache**

[image: Apache]

**Firefox screenshot**

[image: Firefox screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is related to your MAMP version but to the site not being able to load all CSS/JS files
If you inspect the the page, and go to the 'network' tab, you will see if the CSS & JS files were loaded or not found.

If the case is that there were not found, try this:

a) access the Drupal's "Performance" page:
/admin/config/development/performance

b) Under 'Bandwidth Optimization' deselect:

1. aggregate CSS files
2. aggregate JS files

'Save Configuration'

c) clear cache

You may then select to aggregate the files back

===